# Manejo de formularios en symfony 3

Tags: symfony3

Estoy realizando un sitio web para realizar solicitudes de locales en una universidad

Tengo una tabla referente a los profesores (teacher) que realizan las solicitudes de los locales y otra referente a las solicitudes (request_made) que tiene un campo que referencia a la tabla request_made

Tengo las clases TeacherType.php y Request_MadeType.php que son los formularios de teacher y request_made respectivamente

necesito mostrar un formulario que contenga el los dos formularios juntos

**¿Cómo pudiera hacerlo?**

aqui les muestro las clases de las entidades y la de los formularios

```
/**
 * Class request_made
 * @package PrimaryBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class request_made{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="local")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="local_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $local;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="teacher")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $teacher;
...

/**
 * Class teacher
 * @package PrimaryBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class teacher{
    ...
```

Formulario de Solicitudes

```
class Request_MadeType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder
        ->add('local', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'PrimaryBundle:local',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Seleccione el local'
        ))
        ->add('teacher', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'PrimaryBundle:teacher',
            'choice_label' => 'first_name',
            'label' => 'Seleccione el profesor'
        ))
        ->add('start_time', TimeType::class, array('label' => 'Hora inicio'))
        ->add('end_time', TimeType::class, array('label' => 'Hora fin'))
        ->add('date', DateType::class, array('label' => 'Día'))
        ->add('subject', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Asignatura'))
        ->add('faculty', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Facultad'))
//      ->add('state', IntegerType::class, array('label' => 'Estado'))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Insertar Datos'))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' =>     'PrimaryBundle\Entity\request_made',));
}
```

}

Formulario de Profesores

```
class TeacherType extends AbstractType{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
        ->add('first_name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nombre'))
        ->add('last_name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Apellidos'))
        ->add('ci', TextType::class, array('label' => 'CI'))
        ->add('teaching_category', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Categoría Docente'))
        ->add('scientific_category', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Categoría Científica'))
        ->add('user_name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nombre de Usuario'))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Insertar Datos'))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'PrimaryBundle\Entity\teacher',));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar este Bundle: 
https://github.com/MWSimple/AdminCrudBundle

El mismo ayuda a trabajar con formulario embebidos. Aquí está la documentación:

https://github.com/MWSimple/AdminCrudBundle/blob/version30/Resources/doc/formsembed.md

Saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código de cómo se respondería a la pregunta de esta forma?

Comment: Reviso el código que tengo realizado y lo completaría según el ejemplo que indican en la pregunta.